# How to read session value in Service layer when the value was saved in Play controller

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play 2.4. I have a controller which extends `play.mvc.Controller`. There I am setting user object in session as below:

```
session("username", user);
```

Now I want to read this session object in my service class which doesn't extend `play.mvc.Controller`, am not getting how I can read this, so please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by using the `Http.Context` class:

```
import play.mvc.Http;

class Service {

    public void something() {
        String username = Http.Context.current().session().get("username");

        // do something
    }
}
```

But, should you? It is very unusual that a layer that is below (service) know things about the layer above (controllers). The code above is harder to test, per instance. Why not rewrite it so that your service receives what it needs from the above layer?

```
class Service {

    public void something(String username) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And your controller will do:

```
class MyController extends Controller {

    public Result action() {
        String username = session("username");
        service.something(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second solution is also significantly easier to test in isolation.